# Opening .asp Files on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, files

I have to open an .asp file to print it.  I have tried renaming it to .pdf but that didn't work.  Is there a work about on Ubuntu 13.04 for opening these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `.asp` is a special type of webpage. You should be able to open it through a web browser to view it and be able to print from there.

[reference](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/asp)

Comment: Doesn't allow me to open via browser- Firefox.

Comment: When you right click > properties, what is shown in the file type field? Also, try just double clicking the file

Comment: ASP page (application/x-asp)

Comment: There is a image to this one and it doesn't show

Comment: Strange thing is, when I re-do the quiz for the lab safety and get 100%, the .asp works, but not when I get the .asp.

Comment: @Barsook What does it say when you open it with firefox?

Comment: It goes back to the download screen.

Comment: @Barsook I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. Is this file on the internet or has it been downloaded? Try downloading it then opening

Comment: Did that and it came back to that.

Comment: @Barsook take a look at this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/run-aspnet-applications-on-ubuntu-for-developers/ then try opening the page again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10624/discussion-between-barsook-and-minerz029)

Answer (score 0):

.asp is a plain text file, you can open it in gedit without any problem.

Comment: But you don't the full thing.